# warnings & errors after MAMP to live (hosteurope)

Tags: errors, warnings

I get these warnings after getting live with my wordpress site from local to server.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'bones_register_sidebars' not found or invalid function name in /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 403

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/plugin.php:403) in /is/htdocs/wp1108989_5IDG6XP7VR/www/cgi-bin/website/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
```

hoster is hosteurope. any one any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Just curious, where are you hosting your site? I don't mean the provider/company - I mean what's the URL to where you have your files for your entire website/Wordpress install? From the above, it looks as if you're in the /cgi-bin directory? Is that so?

Comment: We can't investigate any further without seeing the relevant code ( we're not psychic =p )

Comment: See my answer for the bit of code we would need, I've also edited your question to use the code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are warnings, not errors ( edited original question to reflect this ).

You have two options:

- **The easy way** - Turn off displaying errors and warnings, log them to a file instead
- **The proper way** - Fix the warnings, and log them to a file instead of outputting

If you need help fixing the warnings, post your code I'll update my answer with an explanation of what happened and how to fix them. Specifically, the code in your theme/plugins that adds `bones_register_sidebars` which is being complained about by PHP

Comment: the bones comes from the theme i think. i used this on: http://themble.com/bones/. otherwise which code do you need?

Comment: Change line 43 of /library/bones.php to `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'bones_register_sidebars',1,0 );`

Comment: it does not work. but if i delete this line of code it works. why is that??!!  THANKS BY THE WAY

Comment: try 0,1 ( removing that line will break/remove features ). Also change your error log to output to a file, not the screen else you'll end up with more of these issues when you install more plugins!

Comment: perfect!!! 0,1 is working. can u shortly explain me what this line does? (the 0,1) thanks!!

Comment: Its assumed a filter/action function will take 1 parameter if you don't specify how many it takes. In this case the function takes no parameters, and so there's a mismatch! This causes the error, because the function isn't expecting a parameter yet one is given. Adding 0,1 tells the API the function expects no parameters, fixing the issue

Comment: You're best asking this as another question rather than in comments. Consider CDNs